# Barplot and normal plot with a different scale

Tags: r, plot

I have the following code:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
df <- data.frame(countdata = 10000 * runif(10), Modell1 = 30 * runif(10),Modell2=30 * runif(10))
mp=barplot(df$countdata)
lines(mp,df$Modell1,col="red") #implicitno x = 1:10
points(mp,df$Modell1,col="red")
lines(mp,df$Modell2,col="blue") #implicitno x = 1:10
points(mp,df$Modell2,col="blue")
```

The problem now is that the scale level is different. This means that I only get one line on the x-axis. I could solve this as follows:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
df <- data.frame(countdata = 10000 * runif(10), Modell1 = 30 * runif(10),Modell2=30 * runif(10))
mp=barplot(df$countdata)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(mp,df$Modell1,col="red",type="l",axes=FALSE)
points(mp,df$Modell1,col="red",axes=FALSE)
lines(mp,df$Modell2,col="blue",axes=FALSE) #implicitno x = 1:10
points(mp,df$Modell2,col="blue",axes=FALSE)
```

As you can see now, the dots in the graphic are squeezed, which doesn't look so good. Can someone help me solving this problem?

By the way I don't want to divide or multiply my data...(for example Modell1*10000)

Thanks in advance,

Fabian

Comment: I'd advise you to learn `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this sorta what you're looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(id, countdata)) +
  geom_point(aes(id, Modell1, col = "Modell1")) +
  geom_point(aes(id, Modell2, col = "Modell2")) +
  geom_line(aes(id, Modell1, col = "Modell1")) +
  geom_line(aes(id, Modell2, col = "Modell2")) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty) +
  labs(color = "Model") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Which returns:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @tyluRp, that was the solution i was looking for :)

Comment: @F.Schusterschitz Happy to help!

Answer (score 3):

Try this. You can solve the problem by adjusting the **ylim**.

```
plot(df$countdata, col = "gray", ylim = c(0,11000), xlab = "", ylab = "", ty="h", lend="square", lwd=35, axes = F)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(df$Modell1, col="red", ylim = c(0,200), xlab = "", ylab = "", type="o", pch=19, lwd=2, axes = F)
lines(df$Modell2, col="blue", ty="o", pch=19, lwd=2)
```

It returns,

[image]